# How can I pass command-line arguments when creating a new Database connection in SQLPro?

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

When I start my MySQL client from the command-line, I do the following:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 --init-command="SET SESSION wait_timeout=300"
```

I set the session `wait_timeout` to 300 seconds for security purposes. If there is no database activity for 5 minutes, I want the connection to be killed so that it is not actively left open for long periods of time which is a security risk.

However, I really prefer using the Mac desktop application [**SequelPro**](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro) to access the database instead of the command-line shell. It's my bread-and-butter. I absolutely love it. Here's what it looks like when I open a DB connection in SequelPro:

[image]

So how can I give SequelPro the same `--init-common argument I gave on the command-line above? Or is there any other way for me to achieve the security goal I'm trying for?

Comment: did you tried, Host as `127.0.0.1 --init-command="SET SESSION wait_timeout=300"` ?. If that doesn't works then you could try reaching them.

Comment: That didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make this **global** setting for everyone connecting from any tool. You add this to the configuration file, my.cnf (if you're running MySQL on Unix-based OSs) or my.ini (if you're running MySQL on Windows-based OSs).

This is from MySQL documentation about **wait_timeout**

> The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a
>   noninteractive connection before closing it.
>
> On thread startup, the session wait_timeout value is initialized from
>   the global wait_timeout value or from the global interactive_timeout
>   value, depending on the type of client (as defined by the
>   CLIENT_INTERACTIVE connect option to mysql_real_connect()). See also
>   interactive_timeout.

So, set this global parameter in `[mysqld]` section of your configuration file to keep your security in check.

```
[mysqld]
interactive_timeout=300
wait_timeout=300
```

Comment: I don't own the DB so I cannot make it a Global Setting. I just want it to apply only to my own sessions.

Comment: Not sure if SequelPro gives you that flexibility.

Comment: @SaqibAli - So you are willing to accept security vulnerability from others, just not from yourself?

Comment: @Rick, What?? I'm not the owner of the database. I don't have permissions to set global settings on it.

Comment: @SaqibAli - Request the owner of the database to set global timeout. That way, you will make them aware of this vulnerability.